# Will different RAMs work on my IBM Thinkpad r50e?

Tags: memory, thinkpad, ddr

I have an old IBM Thinkpad r50e, it has 2x256MB DDR1 RAM, which I would like to upgrade. I am going to buy a 1GB RAM, and my question is the following:
Can I use one of the 256MB one with the new 1GB, or would it crash being used together, and I should stay with one 1GB only?

Comment: Provided your system supports 2GB of memory you can use a single 1GB module with a 256MB module.  Be sure they are the same frequency and require the same voltage otherwise they won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM ThinkPad R50e supports maximum 2 x 1 GB DDR

For compatible memory specification, refer this link: http://www.memorystock.com/memory/IBMThinkPadR50e1834xxx.html